# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at playMusic

Tags: javascript

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at playMusic, please what could be the solution of this error

html file

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="pause">
          <i id="played" class="fas fa-play"></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

javascript file

```
const playPauseBtn = wrapper.querySelector('.fa-play')
function playMusic(){
  wrapper.classList.add('fa-play')
  playPauseBtn.querySelector('i').innerHTML = 'fa-play';
  musicAudio.play();
}

function pauseMusic(){
  wrapper.classList.remove('fa-play')
  musicPlayPauseBtn.querySelector('i').innerHTML = 'fa-pause';
  musicAudio.pause();
}

playPauseBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

  const isPaused = wrapper.classList.contains('fa-play')

  isPaused ? pauseMusic() : playMusic();
})
```

Comment: You didn't define `musicPlayPauseBtn`.

Comment: playPauseBtn.querySelector('i') this is getting null

Comment: How do you expect that `playPauseBtn` will select `i` tag when it's the `i` tag ? I guess that you done your player at worest way there's more simpler

Comment: I think you have selected the i tag itself with your query and are trying to select another inner i that isn;t there

Comment: @Spectric You are right that `musicPlayPauseBtn` is not defined but OP is looking for `i` as a child element of `i` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are querying the element using the `playPauseBtn` reference, but there is no `i` as a child of `playPauseBtn`

It is the element that you are looking for not the element that is as a child of `playPauseBtn`

So you should use

```
document.querySelector( "i" )  // It will select the first HTML element that is i
```

or

```
wrapper.querySelector( "i" ) // specific i element that is child Element of wrapper element
```